# How to check authentication for hundreds and thousands of API endpoints?

Tags: authentication, go, service

I am currently building a web application in golang (with Gorilla) and have implemented a handful of API endpoints. However, I noticed that every time I implement a function like:

```
func CreateUserHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {}
```

I have to add the function below to the body of handler functions to check if request is authorized:

```
func checkAuthorizedUser (r * http.Request) error {
    uid, err := CheckRequestUser (r.Cookie("uid"))
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Can't find cookie value for uid")
    }
    if !IsValidUser (uid.Value) { 
        return errors.New("Not a valid user")
    }
    return nil
}
```

What happens to me right now is that I have to add `checkAuthorizedUser()` to every handler function, and I have already have a lot of handler functions so far. I wonder if there is a better way to check whether a client is authorized to access certain endpoint other than explicitly checking authentication in every handler function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gorilla has a router you can use. You can then wrap the router with authentication checking. Something like this would work:

```
func checkPermissions(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        authCheck := true //implement the actual checking

        if authCheck {
            w.WriteError(w, 400, "error")
            return
        }

        h.ServeHttp(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/articles", ArticlesHandler)
    http.Handle("/", checkPermissions(r))
}
```

Supporting links:

https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#NewRouter

https://github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: Thanks! However, does that mean the package that wrap the handler function will essentially handle the authentication process? Should authentication be handled by controllers instead of models?